# Explanation of the functoriality of the Euler class in a categorical view

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, differential-topology

I'm reading Bott&Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* and its Proposition 6.39 says that

> The Euler class is functorial, i.e, if $f:N\to M$ is a $C^\infty$ map and $E$ is a rank $2$ oriented vector bundle over M, then
> $$ e(f^{-1}E)=f^*e(E). $$

I have no difficulty understanding this statement, but the word "functorial" is quite confusing to me. Does it mean that the Euler class can be translated into a functor between two categories? If the Euler class can be translated into a functor, then the functoriality statement should be that it commutes with composition of morphisms. However, in the equation, $e$ is applied to a vector bundles while $f^*$ is a induced map, and I just cannot find a category in which two morphisms composite to be the pullback $f^{-1}E$. This is too strange to me.

Can the Euler class really be translated into a functor? Or there is simply another meaning of "functorial" in the field of differential geometry?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Functoriality here means that Euler class is a natural transformation from (certain class of (contravariant) functors) to (cohomology functor).  See [characteristic class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class).

Comment: @user10354138 I see. Thanks!